# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in blablabla

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm creating a file to display my database list to my android app but it keeps me giving this error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\file_location\file_location\file_location\sql.php:40
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\android_p\function\getstudentlist.php(12): classes\server\sql-&gt;get_student_list()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\android_p\classes\server\sql.php</b> on line <b>40</b><br />
```

and i dont know where my error is occured here it is my three file.

this file will save the data in json format for android
getstudentlist.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting( E_ALL );

include("../root/root.php");

use \classes\server\sql;

header("Content-Type: application/json");

$sql = new sql();

if($sql->get_student_list() != "")
{
    $list = $sql->get_student_list();
    echo "{\"students\":";
    echo json_encode($list);
    echo "}";
}
else
{
    echo "no data output!";
}

 ?>
```

this one will execute all the sql command
sql.php

```
<?php 
namespace classes\server;
use \PDO;

class sql extends config
{
    private $con = null;
    private $sql = null;
    private $db = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if($this->connection() != false)
        {
            $this->con = $this->connection();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->con = $this->connection_error();
        }
    }

    private function db_open()
    {
        return $this->con;
    }

    private function db_close()
    {
        return $this->con = null;
    }

    public function get_student_list()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_students
                          ORDER BY stu_lname DESC;";

            $this->db = $this->db_open()->prepare($this->sql);
            $this->db->execute();
            $this->db->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $count_get_list = 0;

            while($data = $this->db->fetchAll())
            {
                $getdata[] = $data;
                $count_get_list++;
            }

            if($count_get_list > 0) { return $getdata; } else { return ""; }

            $this->db_close();
        }
        catch(PDOException $x)
        {
            echo $this->connection_error();
        }
    }
}
 ?>
```

and lastly this file will make a connection form the server
config.php

```
<?php 
namespace classes\server;
use \PDO;

const db_host = "localhost";
const db_name = "dbname";
const db_username = "root";
const db_password = "";

class config
{
    private $connection = null;
    private $db_acct = array("db_access" => ["username" => db_username,
                                             "password" => db_password]);
    private $isConnected = null;
    private $connection_error = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=".db_host.";dbname=".db_name, $this->db_acct["db_access"]["username"], 
                                                                                  $this->db_acct["db_access"]["password"]);
            $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            if($this->connection)
            {
                $this->isConnected = $this->connection;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->isConnected = false;
            }       
        }
        catch(PDOException $x)
        {
            $this->connection_error = $x->getMessage();
        }

    }

    protected function connection()
    {
        return $this->isConnected;
    }

    protected function connection_error()
    {
        return $this->connection_error;
    }
}
 ?>
```

No need to show my root.php file cause the job of that file is to connect all the files only. 
hope you guys could help me!
it means me a lot.

Comment: fyi, you don't need to do all that connect/disconnect checking stuff, it ends at the ends at script execution anyway, remove it and your code would be like 10 lines!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first call to `get_student_list()` sets the `$con` variable to `null`, hence the error message during the second call. It may be worth saving the output of `get_student_list()` in a variable and then working with the variable subsequently... Or change the DB class not to close the connection.